# Creating Trac Tickets From Website

Tags: trac

is it possible for my website visitors to create Trac tickets from my website rather than being logged into the Trac system?  For example: I have a feedback form on my website that sends the form information to an e-mail address.  What I would like to do is have that form communicate with Trac and dynamically create a ticket with each form submission, instead of sending an e-mail.

I've taken a look at the page source of the "New Ticket" page on Trac.  It looks like the form has a hidden input field with the name "__FORM_TOKEN" and generates obscure data for the field's value that seems to be generated randomly.  I'm guessing this is a security measure (probably to block users from attempting cross-domain communication?)

Simply copying the form's action field with the appropriate hidden fields onto my website form doesn't do the trick.

Is what I am doing even possible?  Trac doesn't seem to serve this kind of purpose.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [email2trac](https://subtrac.sara.nl/oss/email2trac) to have the e-mail sent to Trac to create the ticket.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign the TICKET_CREATE permission to the *anonymous* group, everyone can create tickets with no need to login.