# Create Trac ticket from Google Form GAS script?

Tags: google-apps-script, trac, google-forms

This is a followup question to my original question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950617/is-there-a-simple-bugzilla-trac-client-for-use-by-non-software-folks).  The decision between Bugzilla & Trac seems to have been made for us, and Trac it is.  Here are the options I've found so far:

- Leverage our current Google Form based bug report by modifying the GAS script that is doing our email notification.  So far I've been unable to find an example, but it would appear that you can modify the email portion of the GAS script to send email to the Trac server to open a ticket automatically.  This is my preferred option, but I'd like to see an example if possible.
- Create something using [TracCmdScript](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracCmdScript), but the site hasn't been updated in three years, and it appears to use python, a language I'm not proficient at (although I'd like to be) and the [XmlRpcPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/XmlRpcPlugin), which seems to be under current development.
- There's also an email option website cited on this SO page to use [email2trac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926554/creating-trac-tickets-from-website), but the cited site appears to be dead.  **Edit**: here's the new site:  [email2trac](https://oss.trac.surfsara.nl/email2trac/wiki/Email2tracInstallation/Windows) which still hasn't been touched in a couple of years, but seems to be functional.

I'm open to any other suggestions the SO folks might have.

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution? We use a customized email2trac extensively both for creating new tickets and updating existing tickets via email; I'd be happy to share what I know!

Comment: @mjk I'd be very interested to learn what you can teach me.  This project has gotten a bit sidelined due to other constraints, but we're still very interested in getting it going

Answer (score 0):

I have found the XMLRPC plugin to be the most reliable way of automating interaction with Trac.  Practically every major programming/scripting language has libraries available for doing either XML RPC or JSON RPC calls, which means that most of the difficult stuff will be handled for you.  If you already have a script that takes the submitted form data and formats it into an email, then you should be able to modify that script to take the same data and format it into XML or JSON and shuffle it off to Trac.  The [XMLRPC Plugin's website](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/XmlRpcPlugin) includes some sample code in multiple languages for sending RPC commands to a Trac server.

Comment: We're using a GAS script that's just Javascript on the backend of the Google Form.  Currently it's just sending confirmation emails to the bug filer and our generic bug handler address.  I'll take a look at the examples you've cited and see what we can figure out.  Thanks for the pointer.